# How to bind items to Listview

Tags: c#, wpf

I am dynamically binding item source to Listview.The items itself are dynamically binded.Here is my code..

```
    private void DisplayListView()
    {
        _MyControls = new ObservableCollection<MyControl>();
        _MyControls.Add(GetInnerelementsInfo());

    }
    private MyControl GetInnerelementsInfo()
    {
        records = new ObservableCollection<Record>();
        records.Add(new Record(new Property("FirstName", "ABC"), new Property("LastName", "DEF")));
        records.Add(new Record(new Property("FirstName", "GHI"), new Property("LastName", "JKL")));
        MyHeader = "Headername";

        var columns = records.First()
            .Properties
            .Select((x, i) => new { Name = x.Name, Index = i })
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            var binding = new Binding(string.Format("Properties[{0}].Value", column.Index));
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = column.Name, Binding = binding });
        }
        MyControl c = new MyControl(MyHeader,records);
        return c;

    }
```

and in my XAML code I have

```
    <ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_MyControls}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Path=MyHeader}">
                    <StackPanel Margin="10,4,0,0">
                        <DataGrid
x:Name="dataGrid"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=records}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The error is 'datagrid does not exist in current context' 
Also can anyone tell me if this is the efficient way to do it ..

Thanks
Kyle

Comment: your `datagrid` is inside a `DataTemplate`, that's why you won't be able to find it by its name. Try to get its instance first.

Comment: justin I really dont know how to do that...I am newbie to WPF

Answer (score 1):

Since your datagrid is inside the DataTemplate you cant directly access them in code behind using the x:Name attribute.

Instead what you can try is just fire the loaded event of that grid view in Xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Loaded="dataGrid_Loaded" />
```

and inside the code behind use the following code

```
 private void dataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mydataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    }
```

Now you can access to the datagrid using mydataGrid.